# Combine several mssql database to one mysql with php

Tags: mysql, sql-server, import

We are handling a data aggregation project by having several microsoft sql server databases combining to one mysql database. all mssql database have the same schema.

The requirements are :

- each mssql database can be imported to mysql independently
- before being able to import each record to mysql we need to validates each records with a specific createrias via php.
- each imported mssql database can be rollbacked. It means even it already imported to mysql, all the mssql database can be removed from the mysql.
- we would still like to know where does each record imported to the mysql come from what mssql database.

  All import process will be done with PHP .

  we have difficulty in many aspects.  we don't know what is the best approach to solve our problem.

  your help will be highly appreciated.

  ps: each mssql database has around 60 tables and each table can have a few hundred thousands .

Answer (score 1):

Don't use PHP as a database administration utility. Any time you build a quick PHP script to transfer records directly from one database to another, you're going to cause yourself a world of hurt when that script becomes required for production operation.

You have a number of problems that you need solved:

- You have multiple MSSQL databases with similar if not identical tables.
- You have a single MySQL database that you want to merge the data into.
- The imported data must be altered in a specific way before being merged.
- You want to prevent all duplicate records in your import.
- You want to know what database each record originally came from.

The solution?

1. Analyze the source MSSQL databases and create a merge strategy for them.
2. Create a database structure on the MySQL database that fits the merge strategy in #1, including all the new key constraints (like unique and foreign keys) required for the consolidation.

At this point you have two options left:

1. Dump the data from each of the source databases into raw data using your RDBMS administration utility of choice. Alter that data to fit your merge strategy and constraints. Document this, and then merge all of the data into your new database structure.
2. Use a tool like [opendbcopy](http://opendbcopy.sourceforge.net/) to map columns from one database to another and run a mass import.

Hope this helps.

Comment: we have to use PHP and mysql as specified in the title of the  question. we need to control the insertion of each record via PHP . msssql databases have the same schema. we need all record from all of these mssql to be inserted into just one mysql database except some records that are met our criterias will be rejected .

Comment: Define "control the insertion of each record". There are exceptionally few places where PHP (a programmable hypertext preprocessor) should be used as a database administration utility.

Comment: before inserting to mysql database, each record from Mssql server must pass our validation logic. this validation process will be done with php.

Comment: So let me get this straight: you don't understand why you've having trouble using a tool in a way it was never meant to be used, and you also refuse to use anything but the very same tool that doesn't work?

Comment: please read the question title. PHP needs to be used in the project.